# Why is the result only 81 when I try to use array

Tags: java, arrays

Thanks for reading my question:

```
public class Gugudan_array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 2; i<10; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j<10; j++) {
                System.out.println(i * j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        
    }
}
```

In the multiplication table above, result comes correctly from 2-9, however:

```
public class Gugudan_array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] result = new int[10];
            for(int h = 0; h < result.length; h++) {
                for(int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
                    for(int j = 1; j<10; j++) {
                        result[h] = (i * j);
                        }
                }
            }
            for(int a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {
                System.out.println(result[a]);
            }
    }
}
```

In this code with array, the result comes out only 81.
What have I done wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Your two inner loops essentially just become `result[h] = 9 * 9;` since you constantly overwrite the same element

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to think logically about how the code works. When you put the `j` loop inside the `i` loop, it means that there will be a *complete new set* of `j` values used *for each* `i` value, right? That's how you get the full table of data, right? So... when you put the `i` loop inside the `h` loop... it will work the same way, right?

Comment: Also, think carefully - how many values do you want to be calculated, in total? Therefore, what should be the size of `result`? Next - suppose you have a variable `h` that tells you the position in the array where each value should be written. **When** should it increase?

Comment: Today would be a good day for you to learn to use your debugger.  It lets you run your program a line at a time, checking the values of the different variables at each step. 
 If you used it, you'd see almost instantly why your `result` array fills up with `81`.

Answer (score 2):

I'll first explain why your code doesn't work, and then go over a correct solution:

```
public class Gugudan_array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] result = new int[10];
            for(int h = 0; h < result.length; h++) {
                for(int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
                    for(int j = 1; j<10; j++) {
                        result[h] = (i * j);
                        }
                }
            }
            for(int a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {
                System.out.println(result[a]);
            }
    }
}
```

The main problem lies in this chunk of code:

```
for(int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
   for(int j = 1; j<10; j++) {
      result[h] = (i * j);
   }
}
```

Here, you are constantly overwriting the value of `result[h]`, so that once the loop ends and both `i = 9`, and `j = 9`, the code will execute `result[h] = 9 * 9` and then continue on to the next `h`.

My solution:

```
public class Gugudan_array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] result = new int[10];
        for(int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
            for(int j = 1; j<10; j++) {
                result[i - 2] = (i * j);
            }
        }
        for(int a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {
            System.out.println(result[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
18
27
36
45
54
63
72
81
0
0
```

First, notice how I completely got rid of the `h` loop. That is because we can make the index in terms of `i`. When we determine the first number, when `i = 2`, we want to store that number in the `0`th index of our array. Similarly, when we get our second number, when `i = 3`, we want to store the result in the `1`st index of our array.

To summarize, whenever we calculate a result, we will want to store it in the `i - 2`th index of our array.

Better Solution using 2D arrays:

```
    int[][] result = new int[8][9];
    for(int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
        for(int j = 1; j<10; j++) {
            result[i - 2][j - 1] = (i * j);
        }
    }
    for(int a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {
      for(int b = 0; b < result[a].length; b++){
        System.out.print(result[a][b] + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
```

Output:

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 
4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 
5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 
6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 
7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 
8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 
9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81
```

Note: If you want the output to match your original code, change `System.out.print(result[a][b] + " ");` to `System.out.println(result[a][b])`

It would make the most sense to store a multiplication table in a 2D array.

This code works by mapping `i * j` to the `[i - 2][j - 1]`'th element of the 2D array, so that `2 * 1`, will end up in `result[0][0]`

I hope this made sense! Please let me know if you need any further help or clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase `h` variable after all iteration. Here is whole code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] result = new int[10];
    for (int h = 0; h < result.length; h++) {
        for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
                result[h] = (i * j);
                if (h < 9) {
                    h++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {
        System.out.println(result[a]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why even have the first loop if you just skip it with `if (h < 9) {h++;}` ?

Comment: @sorifiend To move to the next element of the array. This is not the right approach anyway, but I showed this approach according to the code shared by the person asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your current setup with 3 nested loops, the outer loop runs 10 times, the middle loop runs 8 times for each other loop, and the inner loop runs 9 times for each middle loop, which gives a total of 10x8x9=720 times... but I suspect you just want 72 results like you show in your first example, so we need to remove the outer loop first `for(int h = 0; h < result.length; h++) {`.

Now the issue is that we need to store all 72 results but your current array only fits 10 results `int[] result = new int[10];`, we can solve this with a bigger array:

```
int[] result = new int[8 * 9]; //72 spaces
```

Here is a working solution with a long array and a counter that keeps track of where to store the value, note the code comments for extra details:

```
//Your loops calculate 8 * 9 results, so you need an array with 72 spaces
int[] result = new int[72];

//Use a variable to track the array location
int counter = 0;

//Youn only need two loops
for(int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j< 10; j++) {
        //Save the result in the correct location
        result[counter] = (i * j);
        //Incriment the counter
        counter++;
    }
}

//Print the stored results
for(int a = 0; a < result.length; a++) {
    System.out.println(result[a]);
}
```

Some further important reading from the official Java guide on Arrays:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

A better solution would be to use a 2D array.